# Logo critique: Which version is stronger?

Tags: logo, critique

A couple logo options for a food and brewing blog written by a nutritionist who grew up on a farm.

Tagline: ***"An exercise using food and drink as a means to discover peace and happiness."***

I'm still in the preliminary stages. Option 1 is a combination of a pea, hop, and smiley face. Does anyone see that?

[image: food blog logo]

Comment: Now that you mention it, yes. I might possibly have gotten the smiley face, but probably more by chance than by obviousness. Wouldn't have gotten the pea in a million years. As regards the name, I don't know whether it's intended or not, but my immediate thought was that it would be about beer, not dietitian-y stuff. It's a very clever pun, but I would guess that beer would be quite a pervasive association with most people.

Comment: I agree about the beer, but that's probably the fault of the hop. What interests me more is the overall look. It is heavy, settled (which is good for beer). But diet should probably light and elegant (have you looked at competitors logos?). So I don't think its about seeing the elements, it's about visually miscategorizing it into a different field. So take one step back and look at the values you want to convey and which logos do that. And how is the look of the competition.

Comment: This isn't a critique site. But while the question is open... Go with the second direction. It conveys the earthy, farm-to-table, craft mood you're probably after. The first one looks like clothes for toddlers.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I'm new to the site and did not realize it is meant more for technical questions than for design feedback.

Comment: Hi @CaitK I agree about the beer connotation - the hop symbol is strong sign of that. However of the two logos, I think the second has a lighter, perhaps even healthier(?) tone of voice. I think the pea is a bit lost in the first logo. If you were to replace the hops with a wavy/vitalic pea pod in a similar style, I think you'd be on to a winner. Some inspiration: http://www.stevennoble.com/main.php?g2_view=core.DownloadItem&g2_itemId=1437&g2_serialNumber=3 Image Cr.:stevennoble.com Maybe you could exaggerate the curved pod as a smile, and remove the fill of the hop

Answer (score 2):

The first logo just doesn't read as well as the second option. You can easily see the hops, peas, and farm without having to look for it. The only problem I am having with the second option is the stroke of the artwork creates a tension with the name looped over the top. Maybe lessen the stroke of the artwork or adding more space between the name and art could work. I like it though.

Answer (score 0):

I was instantly drawn to the **second one**, because the lines are very clean. It's good work, and I only have a couple of comments about it:

- As much as I like n. 2 (and I do a lot!), it feels a little ***stiff***, and I think it's because of the central object and its interaction with the bottom one. My first thought about the logo was that it was for an artichoke farm. And I would really be ok with that (a central, static artichoke with the fields around, it has a certain poetry!), but when I realised it was for a blog I instantly thought: Is there a message behind the choice of position? A blog makes me think of creativity, flexibility. Why not try the artichoke as less of a feature and more of a "conversation" with the rest of the elements? Or, if you want to make it a big feature, why not go for it fully? Right now your artichoke and your peas are fighting for attention, and my brain can't decide which one is more important.
- Why is the color only in the central area? Is it because you want to take the focus to the vegetables? Also, why is the tip white? I don't dislike it at all, it just makes me wonder why the rest is black and white. You chose a nice watercolor effect for the green, and I actually wonder if you have tried the whole logo in ***colors*** (plus a line-only version, for print and use on color backgrounds). This is a personal appreciation, but if it looks so good in one object, the whole logo in that effect could be a hit. Also, it's a blog about peace and happiness, green is good for the latter, but also are warmer ones like orange or yellow, and I'd love to see those.